# Уместны ли кавычки?

Tags: кавычки, названия

*Рабочий Ивановской районной конторы «Заготскот».*

Нужно ли заключать "Заготскот" в кавычки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Рабочий Ивановской районной конторы «Заготскот»*.
>
> Нужно ли заключать "Заготскот" в кавычки?

**Нужно.**

Для обоснования этого воспользуюсь той же ссылкой, что приведена в параллельном ответе в этой теме **creativecommas**:

> **[Употребление кавычек при сложносокращенных словах](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/76-kav3) зависит в первую очередь от семантики названия:**
>
> Не заключаются в кавычки сокращенные наименования органов
> законодательной и исполнительной власти (министерств, федеральных
> агентств, федеральных служб, комитетов и др.), например: *Госдума,
> Мосгордума, Рособрнадзор, Центризбирком, Россотрудничество,
> Минэкономразвития, Москомнаследие.* Наименования государственных
> предприятий, учреждений, корпораций, акционерных обществ, а также
> крупнейших банков при употреблении без родового слова испытывают
> колебания: *Рособоронэкспорт* и *«Рособоронэкспорт», Роскосмос* и
> *«Роскосмос», Мосгортранс* и *«Мосгортранс», Промсвязьбанк* и *«Промсвязьбанк», Россельхозбанк* и *«Россельхозбанк»*...

Ну а за многоточием идёт следующее:

> Без кавычек пишется название *Сбербанк России* (последовательное
> отсутствие кавычек при данном наименовании объясняется как историей
> его употребления, так и экстралингвистическими причинами: несмотря на
> то что Сбербанк России в настоящее время является коммерческой
> организацией, у многих носителей языка он по-прежнему ассоциируется с
> госучреждением – в Сбербанке можно получить пенсию, оплатить
> коммунальные услуги и т. п.)
>
> **При употреблении с родовым словом кавычки ставятся**: *акционерное общество «Рособоронэкспорт», ГК «Роскосмос», ГУП «Мосгортранс», ПАО
> «Промсвязьбанк», АО «Россельхозбанк», публичное акционерное общество
> «Сбербанк России»*.

Comment: При употреблении с родовым словом кавычки ставятся в наименованиях предприятий и учреждений — по сути, предпринимательских, деловых структур. Административных органов это исключение не касается. В дополнение я уже приводила выше цитату из "Справочника по орфографии и пунктуации для работников печати" Былинского и Никольского, 1970: "Не выделяются кавычками собственные наименования учреждений, издательств, управлений, строительных контор и т. д.,: Днепрострой, инженер Мосэнерго, руководители Средазгидростроя, контора Главгидроэнергостроя... Политиздат и т. д."

Comment: _creativecommas: …В дополнение я уже приводила выше цитату из "Справочника по орфографии и пунктуации для работников печати" Былинского и Никольского, 1970: "Не выделяются кавычками собственные наименования учреждений, издательств, управлений, строительных контор и т. д.,: Днепрострой, инженер Мосэнерго, руководители Средазгидростроя, контора Главгидроэнергостроя... Политиздат и т. д."_ === Вынужден повторить ещё раз: **«При употреблении с родовым словом кавычки ставятся…»**

Comment: В подтверждение вышесказанного, постановление Совета народных коммиссаров:  https://auction.ru/offer/postavka_mjasa_gosudarstvu_v_1935_g_mjaso_zagotskot-i19021332779658.html#2 - откройте второй разворот, на правой странице в конце первого абзаца жирным шрифтом - отчетливо видно Заготскот без кавычек.

Comment: _creativecommas: В подтверждение вышесказанного, постановление Совета народных коммиссаров: https://auction.ru/offer/postavka_mjasa_gosudarstvu_v_1935_g_mjaso_zagotskot-i19021332779658.html#2_ === Честно говоря, не понял, что Вы этим постановлением хотели подтвердить!

Comment: @creativecommas А там (на странице) нет родового слова.

Comment: @slava1947 Хотела подтвердить, что пишется без кавычек, но на момент публикации не видела, что вы настаиваете на роли родового слова. Не готова ни согласиться, ни аргументированно продолжить спор. Изучу и вернусь.

Comment: _creativecommas: Хотела подтвердить, что пишется без кавычек, но на момент публикации не видела, что вы настаиваете на роли родового слова. Не готова ни согласиться, ни аргументированно продолжить спор. Изучу и вернусь._ === Под каким именем вернётесь? 

Comment: @slava1947 - у меня только одно – creativecommas, других нет.

Answer (score 3):

**Я бы писала без кавычек**, поскольку это скорее название местного органа управления, нежели собственное наименование компании.

**[Употребление кавычек при сложносокращенных словах](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/76-kav3) зависит в первую очередь от семантики названия:**

Не заключаются в кавычки сокращенные наименования органов законодательной и исполнительной власти (министерств, федеральных агентств, федеральных служб, комитетов и др.), например: *Госдума, Мосгордума, Рособрнадзор, Центризбирком, Россотрудничество, Минэкономразвития, Москомнаследие*.
Наименования государственных предприятий, учреждений, корпораций, акционерных обществ, а также крупнейших банков при употреблении без родового слова испытывают колебания: *Рособоронэкспорт и «Рособоронэкспорт», Роскосмос и «Роскосмос», Мосгортранс и «Мосгортранс», Промсвязьбанк и «Промсвязьбанк», Россельхозбанк и «Россельхозбанк»*...

Сложносокращенные названия коммерческих организаций пишутся в кавычках и при наличии родового слова, и при его отсутствии: *«Росгосстрах»  и ПАО «Росгосстрах», «Технопромэкспорт» и ОАО «Технопромэкспорт»,  «Строймонтаж» и ЗАО «Строймонтаж»,  «Метрогипротранс» и проектная организация «Метрогипротранс»*.

Comment: Районная контора "Заготскот" это отделение (в каждом районе области) областной конторы "Заготскотооткорм", которая в свою очередь подчинялась "Росглавзаготскотооткорм" Министерства промышленности мясных и молочных продуктов СССР.

Comment: Я решила, что вы "шифруетесь", уж больно вычурно звучит. В художественной литературе 20 века встречается написание и с кавычками и без, но вот из "Справочника по орфографии и пунктуации для работников печати" Былинского и Никольского, 1970: 
"Не выделяются кавычками собственные наименования учреждений, издательств, управлений, строительных контор и т. д., представляющие собой сложное сокращенное слово, образованное из полного официального названия учреждения: _Днепрострой, инженер Мосэнерго, руководители Средазгидростроя, контора Главгидроэнергостроя... Политиздат_ и т. д.